# Excel Count Ifs depending on a sum of 2 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I work with large data sets that have the same description for cases that need to be broken apart. The only way to consistently distinguish the cases is based on the sum of 2 other columns. I am trying to get a count where the sum matches a value I specify. The length of the columns is variable, so I need to include the entire column.

Example:

[image: Sample Table]

I want to count Type A where the sum of columns B & C is 3. I've tried variations of =countifs(A:A,"Type A",sum(B:C),3) with and without the sum function but am pretty sure this is the wrong approach.

Comment: Use a helper column that does the sum

Comment: Hi Scott,

Thanks for the suggestion, this could certainly work. I'm hoping for a more direct solution since I don't have control over the source data and I am trying to make it as simple as possible for other staff to use the tool. We perform this several times each day, so avoiding this step would be preferred.

I suppose I could write a short VBA code that would insert the column and do this, so people just click a button.

Comment: Any other formula solution will be an array type formula.  And array type formulas should be limited to the data source range and not full column references.  That being said if you are only doing one of them the tax on the calc is not too bad: `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="Type A")*(B:B+C:C=3))`  But realize that if you are doing many that the calc times will increase exponentially.

Comment: @ScottCraner would the headers throw that `SUMPRODUCT` off? That was my thought, but getting a `#VALUE!` because of the sum of text...

Comment: What about (on sample data) `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))="TypeA")*((B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B))+C2:INDEX(C:C,COUNTA(C:C)))=3))`

Comment: Scott Craner - This does the trick - thank you very much! My data doesn't actually have headers, I included them for clarity so I am able to do this on the entire columns. 
I am new to posting on this site, is there a way I can mark your answer as solving this?

Comment: @ScottCraner, you should post your answer, and if you want to include the version I gave as it should be less "heavy".

Comment: As an additional note for anyone else who may be referring to this, the next thing I needed to do here was to add up the totals of columns B & C where the criteria was satisfied. This was done by extending out the formula something like this:

=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="Type A")*(B:B+C:C=3),B:B) to get the sum of column B where B+C=3 and the description is Type A.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter this array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(A:A="Type A", IF(B:B+C:C=3,1,0),0)))
```